# Rails using symbol path with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to integrate Breadcrumbs on Rails with Zurb Foundation to add some decent styling,
but I am having trouble extracting the breadcrumb path and using it with link_to.

A breadcrumb looks like this:

```
#<BreadcrumbsOnRails::Breadcrumbs @name="Survey Groups", @path=:organisation_survey_group_path, @options={}>
```

My markup looks like this:

```
ul.breadcrumbs
        -@breadcrumbs.each do |crumb|
            li
                - klass = 'current' if crumb.name == @breadcrumbs.last.name || ''
                = link_to crumb.name, crumb.path, class: klass
```

and the error message that I keep getting is:

```
undefined method `root_path_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000073f08e8>:0x00000005e8df00>`
```

How do I extract the path from a Breadcrumb object and use it with link_to?

Comment: I guess you need to pass crumb in link_to instead of crumb.path

Comment: If I do that I get 'undefined method `model_name' for BreadcrumbsOnRails::Breadcrumbs::Element:Class

Comment: you have corrupted data in your db

Comment: @apneadiving a Breadcrumb is not a model object, it is built up in the  Controllers, see https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails

Comment: I wonder where does `root_path_path` come from

Comment: @apneadiving thanks!!!! that was the problem, in my ApplicationController I had a                            add_breadcrumb 'Home', :root_path                                  as per the examples on the BoR Github page, but as I was not using their view helper, it turns out that I need             add_breadcrumb 'Home', :root

Comment: @apneadiving see https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails#basic-usage for more on the above, you can suggest it as the answer, seeing as it is my fault for not showing some controller code, that would have lead you to the answer

Answer (score 0):

try to crumb instead crumb.path

```
 ul.breadcrumbs
    -@breadcrumbs.each do |crumb|
        li
            - klass = 'current' if crumb.name == @breadcrumbs.last.name || ''
            = link_to crumb.name, crumb, class: klass
```

Comment: I tried that and I get: 'undefined method `model_name' for BreadcrumbsOnRails::Breadcrumbs::Element:Class –

Comment: I get the same error as above, but here it is 'undefined method, crumb_path'